# Preserving all user data when replacing a failing RAID controller by importing "foreign configuration"

Tags: raid

I intend to replace a failing AOC-SAS2LP-H8iR RAID controller with a LSI MegaRaid SAS 9260-8i controller (offered by our IT facility, who suggests these cards are compatible, but also warns that there are no guarantees). On page 46 of [Supermicro's guide to MegaRAID SAS software](https://www.supermicro.com/manuals/other/MegaRAID_SAS_Software_Rev_I_UG.pdf), there is the following definition,

> A foreign configuration is a RAID configuration that already exists on a replacement set of drives that you install in a computer system.

and also details on p. 301 (section 11.5.4) how to accomplish import of this configuration. To  be clear, I want to preserve *all the actual user data on the extant RAID5 drive array*. Referring to the definition above, am I correct in assuming that when the failing AOC-SAS2LP-H8iR controller is pulled and replaced with the new LSI MegaRaid SAS 9260-8i card, that the WebBIOS utility of the new card will detect the existing RAID configuration as foreign, and that I should import this configuration in order to preserve user data?

Comment: It should but if it doesn’t that’s when your backup will be used

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound, apologies for late response, data were preserved without difficulty.